# Why may an overflow occur in the following program?

Tags: c, integer, integer-overflow

```
void main () {
  int i;
  if (i < 0) { i = -i; };
}
```

Can anyone help me to understand why an overflow may occur in the above program?

Comment: Undefined behaviour. The variable isn't initialized. And negating the most negative possible integer yields the same value in two's complement arithmetic

Comment: In 2's complement, | INT_MIN | > INT_MAX

Comment: When `i == INT_MIN` in two's complement notation.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

An overflow may occur because the range of integer representation in two's complement is not symmetric: the magnitude of the smallest negative number that can be represented is the magnitude of the highest positive number that can be represented, plus one. For example, on a 32-bit system the values are `-2,147,483,648` and `2,147,483,647`. That's why negating `-2,147,483,648` would result in an overflow: the result of negation, a positive value `2,147,483,648`, cannot be represented in an `int` of the same size.

Note that the inverse of this problem is not true: negating a positive number would not result in an overflow:

```
if (i > 0) { i = -i; } // No overflow here
```

Comment: @Tom please note that MSVC has `#define INT_MIN (-2147483647 - 1)` in `limits.h`.

Answer (score 1):

Your value of "i", in the stack, is undefined when main starts. The start-up code that runs before main() is called can leave anything there.

Addig to that what [Kashif](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7018546/kashif-faraz-shamsi) said, negative integers can go one value lower than non-negative integers as negatives don't need to leave room for zero. A "1" in the sign bit, with all remaining bits zero, causes an overflow when sign reversed.

In 16 bits: -0x8000 == ~0x8000 + 1 == 0x7FFF + 1 == 0x8000

// "-" negative value == invert + 1 == inverted + 1 == final is the same

The likely hood of this value is low, but present. It will not happen unless the stack just happens to contain the offending number.

Answer (score 0):

The cause for an integer overflow is when an arithmetic operation attempts to create a numeric value that is outside of the range that can be represented with a given number of bits, either larger than the maximum or lower than the minimum representable value.

- Well, in your case the variable `i` is not initialized. So what will happen here is that the memory space which is assigned to variable `i` of integer type will be containing some garbage value.
- If by any chance that memory address contains the maximum possible integer value which is `-2^31(-2,147,483,648)` then negating this value will result in integer overflow.

I hope this helps.