# Print an integer digit by digit

Tags: c

I have a function print_number.

The function checks if in front of the number there exists '-', then it reverse the number and takes every digit and prints it. The algorithm works pretty good but if i give -2.147.483.648 ( which should be the bottom limit of an integer ) it pritns -0 and i don't know why.

```
#include<stdio.h>

void    print_char(char character)
{
    printf("%c",character);
}

void    print_number(int nr)
{

    int reverse=0;

    if (nr < 0)
    {
        print_char('-');
        nr *= -1;
    }

    while(nr > 9)
    {
        reverse = reverse * 10 + nr % 10;
        nr = nr / 10;
    }
    print_char(nr + '0');

    while(reverse)
    {
        print_char(reverse % 10 + '0');
        reverse = reverse / 10;
    }
}
```

Comment: Care to use a debugger? ;p

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45652970/971127)

Comment: You can't negate `INT_MIN` in a two's-complement system (using `nr *= -1;`) because the value has no representation. The loop `while(nr > 9)` will not iterate.

Comment: I unterstood. Thanks so much

Comment: Looks like you're converting the positive version of the input. There is no value +2.147.483.648 in a 32-bit signed 2s complement int. The highest value is 2.147.483.647

Comment: Convert your integer to the corresponding unsigned type *before* doing the negation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are doing

```
if (nr < 0)
{
    print_char('-');
    nr *= -1;
}
```

It inverses negative number to the positive one.
If you will run it for -2.147.483.648, you will receive

```
nr = 2.147.483.648 // == binary 1 0000000000000000000000000000000
```

As INT is 32 BIT variable in your architecture (and at least 16 BIT variable by the spec), so '1' overflows it and so on

```
nr = 0 // For gcc-like C realisation
```

And accepting the ISO9899 spec, this behaviour of signed int overflow is realisation-specified thing and may not be predicted in common.

Use long long value if you're needing to use your program for larger values.
Something like:

```
#include<stdio.h>

void    print_char(char character)
{
    printf("%c",character);
}

void    print_number(long long nr)
{
    int reverse=0;

    if (nr < 0)
    {
        print_char('-');
        nr *= -1;
    }

    while(nr > 9)
    {
        reverse = reverse * 10 + nr % 10;
        nr = nr / 10;
    }
    print_char(nr + '0');

    while(reverse)
    {
        print_char(reverse % 10 + '0');
        reverse = reverse / 10;
    }
}

void main(void){
    print_number(-2147483648LL);
}
```

And test:

```
> gcc test.c
> ./a.out 
-2147483648
```

Comment: How will `long` help? Did you mean `long long`?

Comment: `INT_MIN * -1` causes an overflow and the result is undefined.

Comment: No, "long int" is enougth, see the demo I\ve attached on post update. long int makes variable twice larger than without long, so on it's enougth to store +2147483648 value.

Comment: About undefined - yes, you are particularry right, but in really it will be calculated for 32 bits, so we can predict that it will be zero (1[overflow] 000...000[32 zeros]).

Comment: No, it is undefined, so nothing can be "predicted". a 32-bit `int` cannot hold 33 bits. Your code prints`-0`. And `sizeof(long)` is 4 on my system, hence my remark about using `long long`.

Comment: Ok, so you need to use long long :)

Comment: Yes, I have checked the specification, the long long is the right cross-compilator version. I have fixed my answer and example.

Comment: My compilation gives the wrong answer `2147483648` (not negative). Note that the compiler issues a warning for `-2147483648` because it is undefined behaviour: `2147483648` is not a value in range of `int` so it cannot be negated. Also see that MSVC has `#define INT_MIN (-2147483647 - 1)` in `limits.h` for this very reason. I suggest `print_number(-2147483648LL);`

Comment: Which compilator have you used for it? Does it works ok with -2147483648LL ?

Comment: Yes it does work, and solves compiler warnings. As I said your code has ***undefined behaviour*** which might work, might not work, or may have unpleasant side effects. `2147483648` is not an `int` value so it cannot be parsed correctly, let alone negated.

Comment: @WeatherVane, about undefined result of MIN_INT*-1 - we need to know how this code compiles. In most cases in uses IMUL instruction for signed int multiplication, it correctly calculates young 32 bits, only 33th bit will be lost and OF/CF flags will be up. So we can predict zero-value here. Spec: http://felixcloutier.com/x86/IMUL.html

Comment: "In most cases" I was not talking about what you hope the processor will do, but what C says on the tin. The overflow of signed integer arithmetic is undefined behaviour. `2147483648` *is not representable as a signed 32-bit `int`*. I am not going to say it again.

Comment: Do you have a specification link with pointer to the undefined behaviour? :)

Comment: This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3948479/integer-overflow-and-undefined-behavior) discusses integer overflow. Here is a [draft C spec](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) see section 6.2.5.9 for description of `unsigned` overflow, somewhere in there is a description of `signed` overflow.

Comment: Here is [another link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19842215/wrap-around-explanation-for-signed-and-unsigned-variables-in-c) and you can google more for yourself. Note the difference between what your processor does, and what the C language specifies - which says that unsigned interger overflow essentially "wraps" but that signed integer overflow is undefined behaviour.

Comment: Seems like the only answer for this question in spec is "..is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised...", so you are right.

Comment: `print_number(long long nr)` and `nr *= -1;` is UB of the minimal `long long`, which may be the same as `INT_MIN`.  "As INT is 32 BIT variable" --> C does not specify that.

Comment: "print_number(long long nr) and nr *= -1; is UB of the minimal long long" - you're absolutelly right, but if author required to work with INT only, it's OK for the example to give understanding about the error reason.
"AS INT is 32 BIT value" - OK, in author's architecture it is 32 BIT, by the spec - 16 BIT, byt anycase I've fixed my answer, tnx. "minimal long long, which may be the same as INT_MIN" --> C99 Spec (5.2.4.2 Numerical limits) says they can't, INT_MIN is at least -32767 AND LLINT_MIN is at least -9223372036854775807, so it will work for "-2.147.483.648" anycase.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the MAX and MIN range for an INT are `-2,147,483,648` and `2,147,483,647` respectively.

 Negating `-2,147,483,648` means a positive value `2,147,483,648` would result in an overflow by 1 as it is out of bounds for the MAX range. 
This operation will result in the same value of `-2,147,483,648`.

Secondly, you might encounter an overflow during the integer reversing process.
Example, reversing `2147483647` causes an overflow after the intermediate result of `746384741`.
Therefore, you should handle that by throwing an exception or returning 0.

Thirdly, your loop for reversing the number is inaccurate. It should loop till `while(nr != 0)`

Here's the complete code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main()
{
    void reverseNumber(int);

    reverseNumber(124249732);
    return 0;
}

void reverseNumber(int nr)
{
    printf("nr = %d\n", nr);

    int reverse = 0;
    bool neg = false;
    if (nr < 0) {
        neg = true;
        nr *= -1;
    }

    while (nr != 0) {
        int digit = nr % 10;
        int result = reverse * 10 + digit;

        if ((result - digit) / 10 != reverse) {
            printf("ERROR\n");
            exit(0);
        }

        reverse = result;
        nr = nr / 10;
    }

    if(neg) {
        printf("%c", '-');
    }
    printf("%d\n", reverse);
}
```

Comment: "Firstly, the MAX and MIN range for an INT are -2,147,483,648 and 2,147,483,647 respectively. " --> C does not specify that.

Answer (score 0):

`nr *= -1;` is a problme when `nr == INT_MIN` as that is *signed* integer overflow.  The result is *undefined behavior* (UB).  Best to avoid.

Wider integers are not always available.

Using OP's general, approach, do not change the sign of `nr` until it is reduced.

```
void print_number(int nr) {
  int reverse = 0;

  if (nr < 0) {
    print_char('-');
    //nr *= -1;
  }

  while (nr/10) {   // new test
    reverse = reverse * 10 + nr % 10;
    nr = nr / 10;
  }
  reverse = abs(reverse);  // reverse = |reverse|
  nr = abs(nr);            // nr = |nr|
  print_char(nr + '0');

  while (reverse) {
    print_char(reverse % 10 + '0');
    reverse = reverse / 10;
  }
}
```